# How to set updated_at into integer column?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a problem with inserting into table where updated_at, created_at, deleted_at have type integer. But as I understood, this columns have default type datetime and when I update note, I have an error like `Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "2020-09-28 04:21:06"`. Therefore when I create a new note, I added this `updated_at = Carbon::now()->timestamp;` But it does not work and I can't change structure of table and type of column

Comment: What error you are getting when you are trying with this `updated_at = Carbon::now()->timestamp;` ?

Comment: pease go database.. change type  `updated_at `  to `timestamp` and set default `null` or `current timestamp` ...

Comment: Why `updated_at` set as integer? it should be `timestamp`, go to pogres admin and check column format. In your migration you have `$table->timestamps();` or you've modified `updated_at` ?

Comment: default type is not `datetime` , default format is `timestamp` both are different. Would you please share the migration file?

Comment: please try it.. `date('Y-m-d h:i:s ', strtotime($date));` or  `date('Y-m-d h:i:s');`

Answer (score 0):

If the columns were `timestamp with/without time zone` as they should, you could simply use `current_timestamp` or `localtimestamp`.

This way, you will have to use the more complicated

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp)`
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [Date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) documentation and set `dateformat` in your Model

```
/**
 * The storage format of the model's date columns.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

**Modify your model's migration:**

Replace

```
$table->timestamps();
```

with

```
$table->unsignedInteger('created_at'); 
$table->unsignedInteger('updated_at');
```

Secondly, if you don't want to set the `$dateFormat` for all your models individually, set it in `BaseModel` and make all your models extend that class:

```
class BaseModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}

class User extends BaseModel {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Aleks Don't downvote without specifying any proper reason. We spend time answering your queries and you just put a downvote, not even caring to specify why you downvoted

Comment: Unfortunately, It was not me.

Comment: What is the benefit to make `created_at` `updated_at` column as `unsignedInteger` ?

Comment: I tried that one in my case but we can use integer as well.